# Valid printf() statements in C

Tags: c, string, gcc, printf, clang

Given that:

```
char *message = "Hello, World";
char *format  = "x=%i\n";
int x = 10;
```

Why is `printf (message);` invalid (i.e. rejected by compiler for being potentially insecure) and `printf (format, x);` isn't?

Is `format` treated as a string literal in this case and `message` as a format string? If so, why?

### Update

---

I know why `printf (message);` is rejected. My question is, why is `printf (format, x);` not rejected too.

I'm using clang. The error message for `printf (message);` is `format string is not string literal (potentially insecure)`.

It compiles fine under gcc. So it does appear to be compiler specific and to do with how clang sets it warnings.

Comment: What is the *actual* error message you're getting, and what compiler are you using? These are crucial pieces of information.

Comment: What compiler? How exactly is it rejected?

Comment: Best to post complete code.  The compiler may see `format` only used once and and optimized `printf (format, x)` such that it knows `format` will not change, even though declared `char *format`.  Possible the compiler saw potential in the value of `message` changing depending on other code. hence the security risk.  Other possibilities exist, but seeing complete code would help.

Comment: @chux I'm not really referring to a specific example. Both character string pointers are defined and initialized together as defined above. In two separate compilations of the code, I'm simply using `printf ()` against each, nothing more.

Comment: In that case, I'd go with @this answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a warning in both cases by enabling the `-Wformat-nonliteral` option, which is not included in either `-Wall` or `-Wextra` (but it *is* in `-Weverything`).

For whatever reason, this seems like an intentional design decision to emit a security warning only when the non-literal `printf` statement takes no additional arguments.  The source code which emits this warning can be found in [`lib/Sema/SemaChecking.cpp`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/Sema/SemaChecking.cpp#L2258):

```
  // If there are no arguments specified, warn with -Wformat-security, otherwise
  // warn only with -Wformat-nonliteral.
  if (Args.size() == firstDataArg)
    Diag(Args[format_idx]->getLocStart(),
         diag::warn_format_nonliteral_noargs)
      << OrigFormatExpr->getSourceRange();
  else
    Diag(Args[format_idx]->getLocStart(),
         diag::warn_format_nonliteral)
           << OrigFormatExpr->getSourceRange();
```

I'd guess that this is for compatibility with existing legacy code, but that's pure speculation.

Answer (score 1):

It is a compiler limitation.

If it is known at compile time that the pointer is pointing at a string literal, then the compiler could check the specifiers and omit the warning.

There is no special reason, why you are getting a warning for one and not the other. Standard doesn't specify anything relevant to this issue. It is just how the compiler is implemented. A different one might warn for both cases, or neither one.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass arguments to be formatted to `printf`, it expects you know that the first argument is going to be a format string. If it weren’t a format string, well, what would it do with all those extra arguments? It’s a reasonable inference.

On the other hand, say we specified no data to be formatted beyond the format string itself. Then what if it did have format specifiers in it? It would always be erroneous unless no format specifiers were in it, and so since there is a safe alternative for *this* situation, it’s warning you.

Comment: Note: passing extra, unused arguments to printf is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Clang has `-Wformat-security` on by default. You can suppress the warning by passing the option `-Wno-format-security` while compiling. That should let you compile `printf(message);`.

You can find the description [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

From the gcc docpage:

> -Wformat-security:
>   If -Wformat is specified, also warn about uses of format functions that represent possible security problems. At present, this warns about calls to printf and scanf functions where the format string is not a string literal and there are no format arguments, as in printf (foo);. This may be a security hole if the format string came from untrusted input and contains `%n'. (This is currently a subset of what -Wformat-nonliteral warns about, but in future warnings may be added to -Wformat-security that are not included in -Wformat-nonliteral.)"

So, if there are no format arguments, it simply checks that the format string is a string literal. And here's the definition of a [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). Starting from C++11, char[] and char*'s are not longer considered string literals. Note that you can make `message` a string literal by making it a `const char[]`.

Coming to the question you raised in the comment, `printf("%fHello")` will generate a warning if `-Wformat` is set.

Comment: But why does it catch `message` and not `format`? I'm not to interested in actually printing `message` since I could do it easily by printing with gcc.

Comment: Edited my answer with a link to the gnu warnings options page.

Comment: does this mean that clang checks the character string first for characters that may cause a problem when converted into a string literal like `%i`?

Answer (score -2):

The function prototype for `printf` is declared as:

`int printf (const char * format, ...);`

where `...` is a variable argument list (i.e. 0 to ∞).

`format` is treated as a format string. If you want print `message` using `printf()` you can try `printf (format, message);` where `format` equals `"%s"`.